# how to use handlbars js helper in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is there any way to use the handlbarsjs helper in the javascript code/function.

As we know we can use it within the handlbars templates. But should we used these helper in the javascript code too?.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all of the helpers are in the `Handlebars.helpers` namespace after you register them.

So let's say you have a helper called `titleCase` that takes in a string and returns a title-cased string, you can do something like this:

```
var title = "foobar string that should be title cased";
var newTitle = Handlebars.helpers.titleCase(title);
// newTitle now contains: Foobar String That Should Be Title Cased
```